# Floor function not symmetric for positive and negative numbers

Tags: python, math, floor

I am using Python 3.4.3. The `math.floor` function is giving me different answers for positive and negative numbers. For example:

```
>>> math.floor (19.8)
19

>>> math.floor (-19.8)
-20
```

Why am I getting this difference in the answer?

Comment: Because math...!? *"Return the floor of x, the largest integer less than or equal to x."*

Comment: `floor` gets you the next integer number that's _lower_ than your number, not "closer to zero". See `help(math.floor)`: "This is the largest integral value <= x."

Comment: -20 is lower than -19.8

Comment: What do you think `floor` does?

Comment: in python 3 i am trying to use string without using str or repr. i was trying to use ` ` this sign to convert int to string. but i failed. i guess either it does not support in python 3 or i am doing it wrong. can anybody explain:                         >>> ID = 32
>>> print("My ID is : " + `ID`)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
*** in ID i have used `ID`, but it shows syntax invalid

Answer (score 16):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor):

> Return the floor of x as a float, the largest integer value less than
>   or equal to x.

The `math.floor()` always returns the closest **lower** integer value. Keeping this thing in mind, `-20<-19.8<-19` So -20 is returned as expected.

On the other hand for positive integers, say 5.5, `5<5.5<6`, So `math.floor()` would return 5 here.

Comment: It also matches [the mathematic definition of the floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344815/how-do-the-floor-and-ceiling-functions-work-on-negative-numbers).  What he's describing is the truncate function, `math.trunc()`, which returns the integer portion of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the floor function rounds down. So 19.8 rounds down to 19 and -19.8 rounds down to -20 since -20 is less than -19.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function that is 'symmetric for positive and negative numbers' try numpy's `trunc()`:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>np.trunc(19.8)
19.8
>>> np.trunc(-19.8)
-19.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int(number)` instead, `floor()` will round down.

Answer (score -3):

The `floor` is the `greatest integer` function, meaning the greatest integer less than a given value.

```
-20 < -19.5 < -19   --> -20 is the greatest integer less than -19.5
 19 <  19.5 <  20   -->  19 is the greatest integer less than  19.5
```

Comment: "least greatest integer" seems like a contradiction, and I can't find any reference of `floor` being called that.

Comment: "least integer" is somewhat misleading too... that's somewhere close to infinity, no?